# Is there proof of equation $P = L - I + 1$ in the $2D$ space from the computational geometry?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, computational-geometry, plane-geometry, discrete-geometry

**QUESTION:** Does exist a proof of statement $ P = L - I + 1$, where $P$ stands for number of   polygons, $L$ for number of line segments, $I$ for number of intersection points, in any arrangement made by finite number of lines in $2D$ space?

**EXAMPLE:** On [Arrangement of lines on a plane, I=10, L=15 and P=6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koEji.png)
obviously there is $10$ intersection points (red), $15$ line segments (blue), and $6$ polygons (made by these line segments), which satisfies the statement because $ 6 = 15 - 10 + 1$.

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATIONS:** In general, for $n$ lines, $n\geq3$ we have $$ I = \binom{n}{2} - I_l $$ and $$ L = n(n-2) - L_l $$ where $I_l,L_l$ stand for intersection points and line segments lost due to parallel or concurrent lines
for any configuration in a plane.

If all $n$ lines are parallel, statement is false, because $0 \neq 0 - 0 + 1$.

**BACK TO QUESTION:** Is this statement $ P = L - I + 1$ true? For arrangement with which conditions? Is there some proof?

**BONUS:** Is there a similar statement in higher dimensions?

Comment: This is [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler%27s_formula) ($v-e+f=2$), counting vertices ($v$), edges ($e$), and faces ($f$) of a planar combinatorial graph, except that you're ignoring the unbounded "outside" face.

Comment: I heard about that, but I forgot name of this formula and could’t study it. I see now it must be connected graph. Time to study it properly. Thank you for your answer.